# Is my lottery program wrong ? or am I so unlucky?

Tags: c#

I made a lottery program : http://yadi.sk/d/bBKefn9g4OC7s

Here is the whole source code : http://yadi.sk/d/rnQMfrry4O8cu

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] loto;
loto = new int[7];

for (int f = 1; f <= 6; f++) {
    loto[f] = rnd.Next(1, 50); // Generating random number between 1-49

    for (int h = 1; h < f; h++) {
        if (loto[f] == loto[h]) { // Check with other numbers for the case of duplicate
            loto[f] = rnd.Next(1, 50); // If there is a duplicate create that number again
        }
    }
}
```

**This section I'm generating random 6 different numbers between 1-49**

*Also I'm wondering in this example, are nested loops increase the spontaneity ?*

I'm getting 3-4 max, this program wrong or am I so unlucky ?

( note that : that's my first program )

For all guys trying to help me : I'm really beginner on programming(c# yesterday | c++ 3 weeks i guess), and if you guys clarify what you mean in codes it'll be great.
And please not give me extreme hard coding examples( I don't wanna quit c# )

Comment: Added source code, sorry i'm new at stackoverflow

Comment: Btw you might get better results when using `rnd.Next(1, 50 * 7) % 50`. Especially for the numbers 1 and 50.

Comment: @FelixK. why, didn't get it

Comment: Its my personal experience. While i understand it i can't exactly explain it in english. But you just make a test and you gonna see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method looks unsafe, as get value from `Random` again in the inner loop does not guarantee that it will return unduplicated value. For low value as 1-49, you can use simple random-picking algorithm like this

```
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
        numbers.Add(i);
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    var loto = new int[6];
    for (int f = 0; f < 6; f++) {
        int idx = r.Next(0, numbers.Count);
        loto[f] = numbers[idx];
        numbers.RemoveAt(idx);
    }
```

Note that this is far from optimal solution in terms of performance, but if you will run it only once in a few seconds or more so it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's correct except for the for loop declaration: remember that arrays in C# are zero-based. Thus the loop should look like this:

```
for (int f = 0; f < 7; f++)
```

or even better:

```
for (int f = 0; f < loto.Length; f++)
```

**Update:** I cannot comment the other answers (too less reputation), thus I have to post it here:

@Dan: only one loop is not correct as it is not allowed to have the same number twice in Loto. In his inner loop, 1342 checks if the created random number already exists, so it is not correct to leave it out.

@James: As 1342 just started programming, it is not necessary to use a static field in my opinion. I guess that he or she has his whole code in the `Main` method so there is no benefit using a static variable.

Comment: Yes feO2x, all my content in one method :D As i said i started yesterday, and i'm trying to learn something on my own experiances,mistakes etc

Comment: Whether the code is inside the `Main` method or not, multiple iterations & instantiation of `Random` will not generate expected results, especially if they are within a short space of time - `static` is the way to go here.

Comment: But 1342 does only instantiate `Random` once at the beginning. Afterwards he just calls `Random.Next`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here - you've got one too many loops for a start, and no comments.

See this (over-commented) example below:

```
// This is static so we don't recreate it every time.
private static Random _rnd;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _rnd = new Random();

    // You can declare and initialise a variable in one statement.
    // In this case you want the array size to be 6, not 7!
    Int32[] lotoNumbers = new Int32[6];

    // Generate 10 sets of 6 random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Use a meaningful name for your iteration variable
        // In this case I used 'idx' as in 'index'
        // Arrays in c# are 0-based, so your lotto array has
        // 6 elements - [0] to [5]
        for (Int32 idx = 0; idx < 6; idx++)
        {
            // Keep looping until we have a unique number
            int proposedNumber;
            do
            {
                proposedNumber = _rnd.Next(1, 50);
            } while (lotoNumbers.Contains(proposedNumber));

            // Assign the unique proposed number to your array
            lotoNumbers[idx] = proposedNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

You should end up with a 6 element long array with 6 random numbers between 1 and 50 in it.
Hope that helps!

Edit:
It's also well worth taking note of James' answer - if you're doing the above in a loop, you'll get the same values every time from Random, due to how the seed is used. Using a static version of Random will give much better results.

Comment: Is this code prevents duplicate random numbers ? Because i tried it in my example with nested loops

Comment: See my edit - Make your `Random` a static variable defined outside of your loop (see James' answer)

Comment: Thanks, tips are really helpful for a beginner like me.
If i define static readonly random, it prevents duplications ?

Comment: Taking into account @feO2x's comments, I've added a second loop.

Comment: Thanks that looks simple and functional, I'll have to keep working hard.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to keep re-creating a new instance of `Random` each time, that's the likely cause of why you keep getting similar values each time. The better approach is to create a `static` instance of `Random` and use that across your entire app - this should give you more realistic results e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
...

static readonly Random rand = new Random();
...

List<int> lottoNumbers = new List<int>(6);
int drawnNumber = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < lottoNumbers.Count; i++) {
     do
     {
         drawnNumber = rand.Next(1, 50); // generate random number
     }
     while (lottoNumbers.Contains(drawnNumber)) // keep generating random numbers until we get one which hasn't already been drawn
     lottoNumbers[i] = drawnNumber; // set the lotto number 
}

// print results
foreach (var n in lottoNumbers)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: Is this code prevents duplicate random numbers ? Because i tried it in my example with nested loops

Comment: @1342 No this code is demonstrating how to generate random numbers in a more reliable way - I thought your problem was you keep generating the same numbers?

Comment: No, I'm generating nice numbers actually.
But, I tried to play myself over 1000 times and I got 4 of 6 max.
%70-80  1 or 0 of 6

Comment: This is functionally better, but could do with some comments. Plus why are we using a List when we know the size of the array?

I'll +1 this when it looks a little better :)

Comment: Nice thank you, I don't know many things like List or .Contains etc. etc.

But i'll note it, and will try to learn it

Comment: @Dan it's pretty simple code to be fair, I have updated with some comments anyway. I have also had 2 down votes for no apparent reason. `List<T>` is a generic structure which allows you to store a list of strongly-typed objects/values, `.Contains` is helper method which is part of LINQ. I will add the namespaces in for clarity.

Comment: Much better :)
Personally, I'd avoid any generics for now - it is his first C# program after all!

Answer (score 1):

For easily testing it, I have left the console logs and static void main for you.

You do not need two iterations for this. Also - arrays are 0 based, so either f has to be equal to 0, or less than 7. I went with equal 0 below.

I have created a recursive method which creates a new value and checks if the array [*contains*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the value. If it does not contain it, it adds it. But if it does contain it, the method calls itself to find a new value. It will continue to do this until a new value is found.

[*Recursive methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3dk2cc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are methods which call themselves. Don't try and fill an array with an index bigger than 50 with this, as you will get an endless loop.

```
private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var loto = new int[7];

    for (int f = 0; f <= 6; f++)
    {
        var randomValue = GetRandomNumberNotInArr(loto);
        Console.WriteLine(randomValue);
        loto[f] = randomValue;
    }
    Console.Read();
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds a new random value to insert into arr. If arr already contains this another
///random value will be found.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arr">arr with already found values</param>
/// <returns></returns>        
private static int GetRandomNumberNotInArr(int[] arr)
{
    var next = Rnd.Next(1, 50);
    return !arr.Contains(next) ? next : GetRandomNumberNotInArr(arr);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we just learn recursive's on C++ (on factorial func ), let me examine this code. Thank you sir

Comment: No problem. Also note that everything in this example is static. You probably don't need that in your program. But I had to make it static for easily copy/pasting and testing :)

Comment: What if i say, i have no idea about static :D I get it, I shouldn't code lottery on this level.

Comment: Of course you should! Learning by doing. Never get discouraged because you have to ask. But static can wait :) Did this work out for you?

Comment: Yes i made a folder for samples, now i'm looking at commands like .Contains  ( next ) etc. etc.
I'll try it by myself again after that

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to simulate drawing 6 lottery numbers between 1 and 50.

Your code has some logic errors, but rather than fixing it I'm going to suggest doing it a different way.

There are several ways to approach this; a common one is this:

```
Create an empty collection of numbers.
while there aren't enough numbers in the collection
    let randomNumber = new random number in the appropriate range
    if (randomNumber isn't already in the collection)
         add randomNumber to the collection
```

But there's another approach which scales nicely, so I'll demonstrate this one (someone else will probably already have written about the other approach):

```
Add to a collection all the numbers you want to choose from
Randomly rearrange (shuffle) the numbers in the collection
Draw the required number of items from the collection
```

This is pretty much what happens in a real-life lottery.

To shuffle a collection we can use the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Here's an implementation:

```
/// <summary>Used to shuffle collections.</summary>

public class Shuffler
{
    /// <summary>Shuffles the specified array.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array elements.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">The array to shuffle.</param>

    public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
    {
        for (int n = array.Count; n > 1;)
        {
            int k = _rng.Next(n);
            --n;
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }

    private readonly Random _rng = new Random();
}
```

Here's a full compilable example. I've avoided using Linq in this example because I don't want to confuse you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            int[] lotoDraw = createDraw();

            Shuffler shuffler = new Shuffler();
            shuffler.Shuffle(lotoDraw); // Now they are randomly ordered.

            // We want 6 numbers, so we just draw the first 6:

            int[] loto = draw(lotoDraw, 6);

            // Print them out;

            foreach (int ball in loto)
                Console.WriteLine(ball);
        }

        private static int[] draw(int[] bag, int n) // Draws the first n items
        {                                           // from the bag
            int[] result = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                result[i] = bag[i];

            return result;
        }

        private static int[] createDraw() // Creates a collection of numbers
        {                                 // from 1..50 to draw from.
            int[] result = new int[50];

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
                result[i] = i + 1;

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Shuffler
    {
        public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
        {
            for (int n = list.Count; n > 1; )
            {
                int k = _rng.Next(n);
                --n;
                T temp = list[n];
                list[n] = list[k];
                list[k] = temp;
            }
        }

        private readonly Random _rng = new Random();
    }
}
```

Comment: (I can see that you are trying to simulate drawing 6 lottery numbers between 1 and 6.) What ?! :O

THIS CODE IS SUPER HIGH LEVEL FOR ME BUT THANKS :)

Comment: The shuffling bit is definitely complicated - in fact, it's not something that most programmers would ever come up with themselves; you learn about it from books and sites like this one! However, if you look at the other functions that use the shuffler, they are fairly straightforward, and it's worth studying them to see how they work. It's stuff that will be fundamental to you while learning C#. But you should use the code from the other answers here for now. ;)

Comment: Got it sir, i think all I have to do work hard and push people hard on StackOverflow :)